# Does mbedTLS works on STM32 F1?

Tags: stm32, mbedtls, stm32f1

The stack **`mbedTLS`** is provided by `ST` for its **`STM32 F7 microcontrollers`** but it isn't for **`STM32 F1`**.

So I wanted to know if there was a reason and if it was possible to make **`mbedTLS`** works on a **`STM32 F1`**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use mbed TLS on any controller.
You can adopt STM32F7 port from CubeMx or use original port https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/tree/master/features/mbedtls/targets/TARGET_STM

You may need to implement your own time() (for timeouts) and mbedtls_hardware_poll() (for random numbers)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you could port the mbedTLS but it would not work very well 
since the F1 series has no crypto support by hardware.

The F1 did not have AES, DES or Hash peripheral. These are only available in the
F4 and F7 series.